# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning DiscordApiError: unknown channel

Tags: javascript, discord

i have a question i created a bot which is a temp vc but i am getting an error which is a discordapierror unknown channel sometimes the bot is deleting the channel sometimes not

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
        let isLeave = (oldMember.channel != undefined)

        if (isLeave) {
            console.log(isLeave);
            if (oldMember.channel.name.startsWith('- ')) {
                if (oldMember.channel.members.size == 0) {
                    oldMember.channel.delete()
                }
                else { 
                    let matchMember = oldMember.channel.members.find(x => `${x.displayName}` == oldMember.channel.name);
                    if (matchMember == null) {
                        oldMember.channel.setName(`- ${oldMember.channel.members.random().displayName}'s Room`)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (newMember.channel != null && newMember.channel.name.startsWith('+ ')) {
            newMember.guild.channels.create(`- ${newMember.member.user.username}'s Room`, {
                type: "voice",
                parent: '809723111477346304',
            }).then(cloneChannel => newMember.setChannel(cloneChannel))
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the error code (node:33) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Create/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/Create/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
at async VoiceChannel.edit (/home/runner/Create/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:355:21)
(node:33) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 9)